# Calculating Binomial Distribution in Excel

Tags: excel, math, excel-formula, probability

- `100000` coins are flipped `1000` times.
- The average number of finding heads is `2.46` and the standard deviation is `1.5674`.
- There are `78` runs where no heads turn up.

Calculate the Binomial distribution for this case, and show that its prediction is close to the "real" value `78`.

The Attempt:

To calculate the binomial distribution, I used `BINOMDIST`, where I set `number=0`, `trials=1000`, `probability=0.5`, and `cumulative=false`. However, the output is `9.3326E-302`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nothing. The question is either mis-stated or wrong. The odds of flipping 100,000 coins and not getting at least one head are negligible.

Comment: @brettdj I thought that too, but I calculated the Gaussian distribution with normaldist using the info above and got 0.075, which sort of makes sense because if you multiply by 1000 trials you get 75, which is close to the actual 78. Shouldn't the Binomial be close to the Gaussian for large N?

Comment: The odds of no heads on a single toss = (0.5)^100000. Which may as well be called zero., or  Doing this 1000 times wont make a difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a fair coin
The probability is not 0.5 but 2.54x10E-3.

```
=1000*BINOMDIST(0; 1000; 2,46/1000;FALSE)
```

give 85.18. This is near to the "real" value

Comment: But in that case it's closer to the Poisson distribution. Shouldn't it be closer to the Gaussian?

Comment: I can`t understand what you mean. BINOMDIST give the probability of "clean" run. Multiplied per the number of trials we have the expected number of them. A point value.